# Fortran gemm function on C-contiguous matrices

Tags: python, c, fortran, matrix-multiplication, blas

I'm trying to do matrix multiplication using the fortran BLAS `gemm` function, see [here](https://software.intel.com/en-us/node/468480).

The signature of this function is, all the parameters' meaning could be found in the above link.

```
call sgemm(transa, transb, m, n, k, alpha, a, lda, b, ldb, beta, c, ldc)
```

My problem is that, I want to use C-contiguous arrays instead of Fortran-contiguous ones, and I've been playing with the above `sgemm` for quite a while, still badly confused.

Please help me to walk through some concrete examples.

All my input arrays are C-contigous.

```
a = [[0,1],
     [2,3]]
b = [[0,1,2],
     [3,4,5]]
# pre-alloc memory for c
c = [[0,0,0],
     [0,0,0]]

# compute c = a * b, which should be as follows
# c = [[3,4,5],
#      [9,14,19]]

# since sgemm assumes Fortran-contiguous, so I thought it would be
sgemm('T', 'T', 2, 3, 2, 1.0, a, 2, b, 3, 0, c, 2)
      ~~~~~~~   ~~~~~~~         ~~~   ~~~      ~~~
    trans both   m,n,k          lda   ldb      ldc

# HOWEVER, c is not what I expected, 
c = [[3,9,4],
     [14,5,19]]
```

Apparently sgemm stores the elements in Fortran-contiguous order, how to solve this problem? Also I don't quite understand how those `m,n,k,lda,ldb` are determined if the `transa/transb='T' or 'N'`, hope you could give me a detailed explanation.

**NOTE**

I'm using this `gemm` function exported from [scipy.linalg.cython_blas](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/linalg.cython_blas.html), which means, I have no other choice instead of playing this Fortran ordering stuff.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to use row-major matrix instead of Fortran style col-major, you could use the CBLAS API gemm. You can choose matrix storage layout with  the first parameter.

https://software.intel.com/en-us/node/520775

---

Or you could still use Fortran API. As changing matrix layout is equivalent to matrix transpose. However you are calculating the transposed C in a wrong way.

Your code calculate C in col-major, but you need a C in row-major. So you need to calculate C^T in col-major by Fortran API, which is equivalent to C in row-major.

It should be

```
C^T = B^T * A^T
```

Basically you need to exchange A and B, and corresponding parameters. For more details about those parameters, you could see this answer.

[Transpose matrix multiplication in cuBLAS howto](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14595750/transpose-matrix-multiplication-in-cublas-howto/14596388#14596388)

Comment: I got your point of `C^T = B^T * A^T`, but I'm badly confused what the `m,n,k,lda,ldb,ldc` should be if I use `transa,transb = 'T' or 'N'`?

Comment: @loganecolss I added a link.

Comment: Yes, sure I know about `numpy.dot`, but what I'm doing deals with `C` arrays, so I use Cython and low-level gemm.

Comment: OK the link should be helpful.

Comment: Know what, your cuBLAS howto answer helps a loooooot, I got it now, thanks so much