# cublas AA' using GEMM

Tags: cublas

I am trying to Find calculate AA' multiplication where A is MxN
I am trying this :

```
    double al =1.0f; // al =1
    double bet =0.0f; // bet =1
stat=cublasDgemm(handle,CUBLAS_OP_N,CUBLAS_OP_T,M,M,N,&al,d_A,M,d_Acopy,M,&bet,d_temp,M);
```

But it gives segmentation error [I found this question but I couldn't follow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14595750/transpose-matrix-multiplication-in-cublas-howto)

could you help me doing the AA', knowing that I manually initialized the Matrices using a double pointer

```
double ** m = (double**)malloc(rows * sizeof(double*));
```

also I saved the values as following

```
int i,j;
//initalize A
for (i=0;i<cols;i++)
    {
     for (j=0;j<rows;j++)
       {
        a[i][j]=A_example[i*rows+j];
        //a[i][j]=my_round(a[i][j]*10000.0)/10000.0;
        }
    }
```

Comment: This is the question you *should* have posted yesterday, not "help me find the cause of a segfault in the following 400 lines of code".

Comment: This was posted before the other one.

Comment: Then even worse. Rules and standards exist for a reason. Follow them and everyone wins.

Comment: I posted the whole code because people ask for what I have implented. Also Pointed where is the error... Anyways i removed the post and still struggling with cublas library.  Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just redefined my matrices the way they define it in their examples. I think the issue is the data layout they use. I couldn't adapt my C matrices to cuBlas format.

Anyways: 
they define it as follows:

```
double *m=( double *) malloc (rows*cols* sizeof ( double ));
```

for data initilizaing:
    int i;
    int j;

```
for (i=0;i<k;i ++){
    for (j=0;j<n;j ++){
        printf (" %5.0f",a[ IDX2C(i,j,k )]);
        }
```

where IDX2C is a macro defined as:

```
# define IDX2C(i,j,ld) (((j)*( ld ))+( i ))
```

and finally I was able to find AA' as follows:

```
double al =1.0f; // al =1
double bet =0.0f; // bet =1
stat=cublasDgemm(handle,CUBLAS_OP_N,CUBLAS_OP_T,M,M,N,&al,d_A,N,d_A,M,&bet,d_temp,M);
```

where A is MxN Matrix.